# CSS, Div overlapping despite margin

Tags: html, css

I have the following Div's:

```
<div id="container" style="width: 60%; height: 30%; margin: 0 auto; max-width: 720px; max-height: 360px"></div> 
<div id="tapecontainer" style="width: 60%; height: 30%; margin: 50px auto; max-width: 720px; max-height: 360px"></div>
```

The lower one slightly overlaps the one above, but when i resize the window, suddenly the Div's "remember" that i have put in a margin, and properly aligns.

Is there any way i can make them align correctly from the start?
Thanks a ton.

Comment: Could you make a live fiddle?

Comment: how much parent element's width? coz' you must perfect calculate if you work with percent(%) value or you'll use Bootstrap/Foundation for css framework (responsive).

Comment: Thanks for all the answers everyone. Somebody actually wrote a comment suggesting i tried using "clear:both", and this solved the problem perfectly. Sadly he seem to have removed his comment, so i cannot give him points.

Comment: set float:left; to #container, #tapecontainer. and set clear:both; between divs. try this..

Answer (score 0):

Try by setting `overflow: hidden;`

Answer (score 0):

Change `margin: 50px auto;` to `margin: 0px auto; padding:50px 0;`...

Thanks hope this works...

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<div id="container" style="width: 60%; height: 30%; margin:auto; max-width: 720px; max-height: 360px"></div> 
<div style="height:50px;"></div>
<div id="tapecontainer" style="width: 60%; height: 30%; margin:auto; max-width: 720px; max-height: 360px"></div>
```